# reliable source "for" or "to" a lot of people?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, collocation

1. Internet is a reliable source ***for*** a lot of people
2. Internet is a reliable source ***to*** a lot of people

Which one is right?

Comment: The prepositions are determined by the noun or verb they modify. In this case, _source_ usually governs _for_, though _to_ is also used. But that's only _source_; other verbs and nouns have different requirements.

Answer (score 1):

*Internet is a reliable source for a lot of people* can also mean internet provides information about a lot of people. So, it's a bit ambiguous. However, such ambiguity isn't present in this context when using *to*.